# Issue with Data Authentication code in CDOL1

Tags: emv

I'm facing an issue with Data Authentication code in CDOL1. The AIP doesn't supoprt SDA neither does the ICC has the tag 93 in any of the 70 or 77 templates to perform SDA. 
However, the CDOl1 has Data Authentication Code as its fields that should be submitted for Generate application Cryptogram. How do I go about getting the Data Authentication code in this scenario?

AIP   : 3800

Byte 1

```
 b1(CDA supoprted)                                : 0
 b2(RFU)                                          : 0
 b3(Issuer authentication is supported)           : 0
 b4(Terminal risk management is to be performed)  : 1
 b5(Cardholder verification is supported)         : 1
 b6(DDA supported)                                : 1
 b7(SDA supported)                                : 0
 b8(RFU)                                          : 0
```

Byte 2

```
 b1(RFU)                                          : 0
 b2(RFU)                                          : 0
 b3(RFU)                                          : 0
 b4(RFU)                                          : 0
 b5(RFU)                                          : 0
 b6(RFU)                                          : 0
 b7(RFU)                                          : 0
 b8(RFU)                                          : 0
```

CDOL1

```
Card Risk Management Data Object List 1: 9f02069f03069f1a0295055f2a029a039c019f37049f35019f45029f4c089f3403
      Amount_Authorized_Numeric: 06
      Amount_Other_Numeric: 06
      Terminal_Country_Code: 02
      Terminal_Verification_Results: 05
      Transaction_Currency_Code: 02
      Transaction_Date: 03
      Transaction_Type: 01
      Unpredictable_Number: 04
      Terminal_Type: 01
      Data_Authentication_Code: 02
      ICC_Dynamic_Number: 08
      Cardholder_Verification_Method_CVM_Results: 03
```

Generate AC1 
    command  :80AE80002B0000000001000000000000500840008004700008401706062122CA329C2400000A34ECCF04F6667E1f000000

```
response :6985
```

Request and Response flow for the card

Application Selection
Request  : 00A4040007a000000004101000

APDU Response
6f308407a0000000041010a525500a4d4153544552434152448701015f2d02656e9f1101019f120a4d4153544552434152449000

[Get Processing Options]

Request  : 80A8000002830000

Response : 770e82023800940808010100100104019000

[Internal Authenticate]

Request  : 00880000049D69CB8500

Response : 7781849f4b8180370c16af6bb1eb04cc2bbe6ad5d0612a76ebad966eb708a9a72814eced6807d64d6ec5ae4070290db34d2bb5272d99af30412bf1102e73c3a88eec4f94cdeb9c4e74e7fcf67c51607071eddf6557d698aab99072818cf9536217b8a453d70483e6736345b87bc11babf84835d44436fff5e0c7cf3a36455208a6a9172483d39f9000

[Read Records]

Request  : 00B2010c00

Response : 704b5713BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBd20102011901042100000f5f200eBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB9f080200025f300202019f1f183139303130303030303030303030303432313030303030309000

[Read Records]
Request  : 00B2011400

Response : 70818c9f420208405f25031608015f24032010315a08BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB5f3401019f0702ff008c219f02069f03069f1a0295055f2a029a039c019f37049f35019f45029f4c089f34038d0c910a8a0295059f37049f4c088e14000000000000000042011e034203440341031f009f0d05bc50bc00009f0e0500000000009f0f05bc70bc98005f280208409f4a01829000

[Read Records]

Request  : 00B2021400

Response : 7081ba8f01059081b0a908db21d6fb4127c1773ee444304e93a7aae7ff224ee9a57d2a42ba56f1eeca490953548442780185defa3324a812e78c4f7221a27aa25cb9deb3db1947f6dc9b6e124d26695a4ef4fa6ff1046e2011927a1fc05a3277601df806afb717b875c48e3bba5ac7a225aefe4869d9cc8b558f3d3dd6cbf783623cd13e450cebba2143cb037bad35800492a0afb7da0460dac23a827adb29350cab8ee139705e1756aece0b9eaeb0989d9960b4afa04168269f3201039000

[Read Records]

Request  : 00B2031400

Response : 702692245f92199f70c9a0648cb24f544d63cd640a5fa96234bcfbf245a123d2c7ff6035bedc99b99000

[Read Records]

Request  : 00B2041400

Response : 7081be9f4681b02c2ddf76f11a5f546f4d32b09a96f7c5fb5a586b946e37d038131a940537cf5bccb1f47a0c4c843e3e5a195bdd53f89cb9ebbaa6d8de316cfe7242a18ad0b79a88ece305146fe9ddeb810da109aff4f2f3c29cc011b67c2abf94c914face03f021fa7142687f1c9c39927a8eea6f53a5b47162e2f70e00c9af775be17fb144319810dd765ee377728eb2d19109af84acf47152cc144124b274158eee08d55766e2d44ffdcc5c2e4fe99199d8d34fd5bd9f4701039f49039f37049000

[ApplicationTransactionCounter]

Request  : 80CA9F3600

Response : 6a88

[LastOnlineATCRegister]

Request  : 80CA9F1300

Response : 6a88

[PINTryCounter]

Request  : 80CA9F1700

Response : 9f1701039000

[LogFormat]

Request  : 80CA9F4F00

Response : 9f4f119f27019f02065f2a029a039f36029f52069000

[Offline Data Authentication]

CA PK Modulus:
b8048abc30c90d976336543e3fd7091c8fe4800df820ed55e7e94813ed00555b573feca3d84af6131a651d66cff4284fb13b635edd0ee40176d8bf04b7fd1c7bacf9ac7327dfaa8aa72d10db3b8e70b2ddd811cb4196525ea386acc33c0d9d4575916469c4e4f53e8e1c912cc618cb22dde7c3568e90022e6bba770202e4522a2dd623d180e215bd1d1507fe3dc90ca310d27b3efccd8f83de3052cad1e48938c68d095aac91b5f37e28bb49ec7ed597

Issuer's Public Key Certificate:
a908db21d6fb4127c1773ee444304e93a7aae7ff224ee9a57d2a42ba56f1eeca490953548442780185defa3324a812e78c4f7221a27aa25cb9deb3db1947f6dc9b6e124d26695a4ef4fa6ff1046e2011927a1fc05a3277601df806afb717b875c48e3bba5ac7a225aefe4869d9cc8b558f3d3dd6cbf783623cd13e450cebba2143cb037bad35800492a0afb7da0460dac23a827adb29350cab8ee139705e1756aece0b9eaeb0989d9960b4afa0416826

Recovered Data:
6A02xxxxxxFF122200A3AE0101B001C0426845C5E84328A7DEA291AF32EBA038691945CC3833400DDBEED0943F3D8B93229AD01DA7C577015AC79AF67F07676F2CCA96C469C07CB0F3D4AFAE61445009CA8135329E4D698E2C3331AD5B067F2CC2E34C890A45247841B720F6A467672DAE6E299E8CD064B1880EF7EC3B50C325425E078A053CFFC8763C1A696429A198B479FC075FC8C1162F64050FAF7748B3F45271637E55249AF5C1D2B435E39FBC

Data Header: 6A

Data Format: 02

Issuer Identifier: xxxxxxFF

Certificate Expiration Date: 1222

Certificate Serial Number: 00A3AE

Hash Algorithm Indicator: 01

Issuer Public Key Algorithm Indicator: 01

Issuer Public Key Length: B0

Issuer Public Key Exponent Length: 01

Issuer Public Key: C0426845C5E84328A7DEA291AF32EBA038691945CC3833400DDBEED0943F3D8B93229AD01DA7C577015AC79AF67F07676F2CCA96C469C07CB0F3D4AFAE61445009CA8135329E4D698E2C3331AD5B067F2CC2E34C890A45247841B720F6A467672DAE6E299E8CD064B1880EF7EC3B50C325425E078A053CFFC8763C1A696429A198B479FC075FC8C1162F6405

Hash Result: 0FAF7748B3F45271637E55249AF5C1D2B435E39F

Data Trailer: BC

Recovered Data validation:

Step 1: CA PK Modulus and Issuer's Public Key Certificate having the same size: Passed

Step 2: Recovered Data Trailer check:       Passed

Step 3: Recovered Data Header check (0x6A): Passed

Step 4: Certificate Format check (0x02):    Passed

Step 5: Hash Input Data: 02545210FF122200A3AE0101B001C0426845C5E84328A7DEA291AF32EBA038691945CC3833400DDBEED0943F3D8B93229AD01DA7C577015AC79AF67F07676F2CCA96C469C07CB0F3D4AFAE61445009CA8135329E4D698E2C3331AD5B067F2CC2E34C890A45247841B720F6A467672DAE6E299E8CD064B1880EF7EC3B50C325425E078A053CFFC8763C1A696429A198B479FC075FC8C1162F64055f92199f70c9a0648cb24f544d63cd640a5fa96234bcfbf245a123d2c7ff6035bedc99b903

Step 6: Hashing Result: 0FAF7748B3F45271637E55249AF5C1D2B435E39F

Step 7: Hash Result Comparison:     Passed

Step 8: Issuer Identifier check:        Passed

Step 9: Certificate Expiry Date check:      Passed

Step 10: RID revocation check:      Skipped

Step 11: PK Algorithm Indicator check:      Passed

Step 12: Issuer Public Key Modulus: C0426845C5E84328A7DEA291AF32EBA038691945CC3833400DDBEED0943F3D8B93229AD01DA7C577015AC79AF67F07676F2CCA96C469C07CB0F3D4AFAE61445009CA8135329E4D698E2C3331AD5B067F2CC2E34C890A45247841B720F6A467672DAE6E299E8CD064B1880EF7EC3B50C325425E078A053CFFC8763C1A696429A198B479FC075FC8C1162F64055f92199f70c9a0648cb24f544d63cd640a5fa96234bcfbf245a123d2c7ff6035bedc99b9

Issuer PK Modulus::
C0426845C5E84328A7DEA291AF32EBA038691945CC3833400DDBEED0943F3D8B93229AD01DA7C577015AC79AF67F07676F2CCA96C469C07CB0F3D4AFAE61445009CA8135329E4D698E2C3331AD5B067F2CC2E34C890A45247841B720F6A467672DAE6E299E8CD064B1880EF7EC3B50C325425E078A053CFFC8763C1A696429A198B479FC075FC8C1162F64055f92199f70c9a0648cb24f544d63cd640a5fa96234bcfbf245a123d2c7ff6035bedc99b9

ICC's Public Key Certificate::
2c2ddf76f11a5f546f4d32b09a96f7c5fb5a586b946e37d038131a940537cf5bccb1f47a0c4c843e3e5a195bdd53f89cb9ebbaa6d8de316cfe7242a18ad0b79a88ece305146fe9ddeb810da109aff4f2f3c29cc011b67c2abf94c914face03f021fa7142687f1c9c39927a8eea6f53a5b47162e2f70e00c9af775be17fb144319810dd765ee377728eb2d19109af84acf47152cc144124b274158eee08d55766e2d44ffdcc5c2e4fe99199d8d34fd5bd

Recovered Data:
6A04BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBFFFF102016080901018001B808719C2BE072F4A98F2E8A7485EBEA7DA2BBCE8ECD288B39AEE371E4ACEC4D1D181A92117C46AE85F44FDA8CE2D42C6A0D868893AD7929A9F2463004063A75A146EF65AEA8F254B4297831FF411C23B22859B411B31E71A778F09CD1035B3619F19D72F334629CBB49246A623B005840A2393D26FD7F88FAA7B9D463A8831FBBBBBBBBBBBB216E43FF2D57A8BC98F4ECE45776BDBADB680B1FBC

Data Header: 6A

Data Format: 04

Application PAN: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxFFFF

Certificate Expiration Date: 1020

Certificate Serial Number: 160809

Hash Algorithm Indicator: 01

ICC Public Key Algorithm Indicator: 01

ICC Public Key Length: 80

ICC Public Key Exponent Length: 01

ICC Public Key: B808719C2BE072F4A98F2E8A7485EBEA7DA2BBCE8ECD288B39AEE371E4ACEC4D1D181A92117C46AE85F44FDA8CE2D42C6A0D868893AD7929A9F2463004063A75A146EF65AEA8F254B4297831FF411C23B22859B411B31E71A778F09CD1035B3619F19D72F334629CBB49246A623B005840A2393D26FD7F88FAA7B9D463A8831FBBBBBBBBBBBB

Hash Result: 216E43FF2D57A8BC98F4ECE45776BDBADB680B1F

Data Trailer: BC

ICC Recovered Data validation:
Step 1: Issuer's PK Modulus and ICC Public Key Certificate having the same size: Passed

Step 2: Recovered Data Trailer check:       Passed

Step 3: Recovered Data Header check (0x6A): Passed

Step 4: Certificate Format check (0x04):    Passed

Step 5: Hash Input Data: 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

Step 6: Hashing Result: 216E43FF2D57A8BC98F4ECE45776BDBADB680B1F

Step 7: Hash Result Comparison:     Passed

Step 8: Issuer Identifier check:        Passed

Step 9: Certificate Expiry Date check:      Passed

Step 10: ICC PK Algorithm Indicator check:      Passed

Step 11: ICC Public Key Modulus: b808719c2be072f4a98f2e8a7485ebea7da2bbce8ecd288b39aee371e4acec4d1d181a92117c46ae85f44fda8ce2d42c6a0d868893ad7929a9f2463004063a75a146ef65aea8f254b4297831ff411c23b22859b411b31e71a778f09cd1035b3619f19d72f334629cbb49246a623b005840a2393d26fd7f88faa7b9d463a8831f

ICC PK Modulus::
b808719c2be072f4a98f2e8a7485ebea7da2bbce8ecd288b39aee371e4acec4d1d181a92117c46ae85f44fda8ce2d42c6a0d868893ad7929a9f2463004063a75a146ef65aea8f254b4297831ff411c23b22859b411b31e71a778f09cd1035b3619f19d72f334629cbb49246a623b005840a2393d26fd7f88faa7b9d463a8831f

Signed Dynamic Application Data: 
370c16af6bb1eb04cc2bbe6ad5d0612a76ebad966eb708a9a72814eced6807d64d6ec5ae4070290db34d2bb5272d99af30412bf1102e73c3a88eec4f94cdeb9c4e74e7fcf67c51607071eddf6557d698aab99072818cf9536217b8a453d70483e6736345b87bc11babf84835d44436fff5e0c7cf3a36455208a6a9172483d39f

Recovered Data:
6A05010908A23CB6491FC29772BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB2248D68D019D96F72D6494F1ED17781C29E50E36BC

Data Header: 6A

Signed Data Format: 05

Hash Algorithm Indicator: 01

Dynamic Data length: 09

ICC Dynamic Data: 08A23CB6491FC29772
Pad Pattern: BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB

Hash Result: 2248D68D019D96F72D6494F1ED17781C29E50E36

Data Trailer: BC

SDAD Recovered Data validation:

Step 1: Issuer PK Modulus and Signed Static Application Data having the same length: Passed

Step 2: Recovered Data Trailer check:       Passed

Step 3: Recovered Data Header check (0x6A): Passed

Step 4: Certificate Format check (0x05):    Passed

Step 5: Hash Input Data: 05010908A23CB6491FC29772BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB9D69CB85

Step 6: Hashing Result: 2248D68D019D96F72D6494F1ED17781C29E50E36

Step 7: Hash Result Comparison:     Passed

[GenerateAC1]

Request  : 80AE80002B0000000001000000000000500840008004700008401706072154A6413F240000A23CB6491FC297721f000000

Response :6985

Thanks

Comment: Why are you expecting SDA ? The objective of doing ODA is to verify the authenticity of the card. In fact online only terminals can work without performing ODA.

Comment: In order to send the Generate AC1 request for this card Data Authentication Code is needed (see the CDOL1 data). For getting the Data Authentication Code we need to perform the SDA, is it right?

Comment: Looks OK. Is this a test card (to simulate a case of faulty applet ) ? BTW what are you trying to do exactly ? build a commercial POS ?

Comment: No, it is a live card. We are trying to build a kernel application for EMV.

Comment: To be honest, i am clueless. But still I would like to see the logs from start till end, unaltered.

Comment: Please review the modified the question with request flow..

Comment: @AneeshVarghese I edited your question and replaced the "dynamic data" with "data authentication code" (which I hope was a typo, but confused me). AFAIK terminal should fill unknown/absent fields with zeroes (which you do). Good luck!

Comment: were you able to fix it. please do not forget to post the answer when you get to the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on your CDOL1 and Log format I am assuming you are using M/Chip4 or M/Chip Advance card. Your assumption regarding DAC and IDN are false - as @adarsh indicated, online only terminals do not need to support any form of ODA. As with any object that you don't have a value assigned you should fill these fields with padding (all zeros). 
The situation you are experiencing is probably the result of internal security control for maximum number of generated cryptograms (you can refer to card application specification for details). 
You need to start using test cards for development as it is also formally forbidden by PCI DSS and PCI PA DSS to use live cards for development and testing.